# JavaScript Error: Cordova + Windows Phone Universal + es2015 shims

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-cordova

I'm  geting `JavaScript runtime error` when I use es2015 (es6) shims in my Cordova 5.3.3 + Windows Phone Universal project.

Error when running es6-shim.js

```
SCRIPT5007: Unhandled exception at line 221, column 7 in ms-appx-web://test/www/scripts/lib/es6-shim/es6-shim.js 
0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'toString' of undefined or null reference
es6-shim.js (221,7)
```

I used the following code for testing:
es-shim v0.33.6, Cordova 5.3.3, Visual Studio Community

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="scripts/es6-shim/es6-shim.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Hello, your application is ready!</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Notes:

- Both es6-shim and core.js have runtime errors.
- Using Visual Studio 2015 Community for IDE and builds.
- The problem only happens with Windows Phone Universal.
- I contacted the creator of es6-shim and he believes Cordova is the problem.  More info: https://github.com/paulmillr/es6-shim/issues/364

Comment: Specifically, it appears as though Cordova + Windows Phone Universal is completely ignoring try/catch blocks :-/

Comment: I added an issue to the Apache Cordova's issue tracking site.  You can see more here:

[https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-9838](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-9838)

In addition, I added a github repository that include code to reproduce the error:
https://github.com/dbiele/Cordova-es6shim-WindowsPH10